# Eclipse: Set "Text file encoding" by code

Tags: eclipse, plugins, delimiter

I wrote an Eclipse Plugin in order to set up a new Java Project that is prepared with files and libraries and other stuff we need every time we create a new project.
Now I would like to set "Text file encoding=UTF-8" and "New text file delimiter=Unix" as well.

For "Text file encoding" I did this by:

```java
IProject project = ...
project.setDefaultCharset("UTF-8", null)
```

And after that in Project->Properties->Resource it is set to UTF-8.

My Question:
But I do not find an IProject-Method that allows me to do the same for "text file delimiter".
Is it possible to do this by org.eclipse.core as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just set in a preferences value.

The code for this is in `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.LineDelimiterEditor` which uses:

```java
String val = ... line separator ...

Preferences node = Platform.getPreferencesService().getRootNode().node(ProjectScope.SCOPE)
      .node(project.getName()).node(Platform.PI_RUNTIME);

node.put(Platform.PREF_LINE_SEPARATOR, val);

node.flush();
```

Note: since this is in an internal class it is not guaranteed to be the same in all releases.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That did it!